# Anonymous browsing solutions other than TOR and HTTPS Google

Tags: browsing, privacy, safe-browsing

Are there any anonymous browsing solutions other than TOR that meet the following requirement:

- quick (TOR goes through lots of slow foreign proxies)
- completely secure and untraceable on which sites you visited, your google searches, your shopping history, habits.

Comment: No such thing as "completely untraceable"

Comment: @Moab: why is that the case?

Comment: Its called TCP/IP protocol, every computer has to identify its IP address, this info is sent with every packet of data whether you are going through a proxy or VPN, and everything gets logged on the internet, they can back trace all the logged IP to find the point of origin, which is You. Its how the bad guys get caught, all it takes is time to find you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a premium VPN, All traffic is encrypted between you and the VPN server, All the sites you visit will believe the traffic to be coming from the VPN provider not your ISP and even then they have the Extenal IP of the VPN provider and theres probably thousands of users that IP all hidden behind NAT.

However I reckon the VPN company will keep logs so be warned its not untraceable.